# Converting formulas of VBA code to excel readable formulas

Tags: php, excel, vba, libreoffice, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to convert formulas/queries wiz. written in VBA code to Excel(PHPSpreadsheet) readable formula.

Eg. I want to convert the following code (written in VBA)

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN A1 = "Sample 1" THEN C1 = "Test 1"
WHEN A1 = "Sample 2" AND  B1 = "Sample 3" THEN C1 = "Test2"
END SELECT
```

To (PHPSpreadsheet readable formula)

`=IF(A1="Sample 1","Test 1")` ...

Is there a way or any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: A ready solution, most likely not. If you have lots and lots of code, you could build a parser to do some/most converts, however if is only a few to convert, likely not worth the effort.

Comment: Hi @DarXyde is there a way to convert the above VBA code to any sql format(preferably MySQL)?